# With Embedded YouTube Video, Create Link that Jumps to Specific Time

Tags: javascript, wordpress, video, youtube

On Wordpress, I'm trying to embed a YouTube video, then include links that jump to specific times in that video. So if I want to jump to 2:00, I can create a link that jumps to that point in the embedded video.

I found a similar question from a few years ago, but I believe the YouTube API has changed. I cannot find any plugins that can do this, so want to do it on my own if possible.

Suggestions?

Edit: Here is the code I've come up with so far. However, the only issue is that if the video hasn't been played yet, then seekTo seems to take a long time. I'm not sure if I should response to the onReady event, or another.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_yt_frameapi' );

function register_yt_frameapi() {
    wp_register_script( 'frameapi', 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_shortcode('ytlink', 'ytlink');
function ytlink($atts, $content = null)
{
    wp_enqueue_script('frameapi');

    $id = $atts['id'];
    $time = $atts['time'];
    $timeParts = explode(':', $time);
    $seconds = 0;
    for ($i = 0; count($timeParts); $i++)
    {
        $seconds += array_pop($timeParts) * 60 * $i;
    }

    return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" ' .
    'onclick="var player = new YT.Player(\''.$id.'\', {events: {onReady: function () {player.seekTo('.$seconds.', true);}}});">'.
    ($content ?? $time) . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: share your code snippet

Comment: I added a code sample of what I've tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I got this figured out finally. I'll post my solution here in case anyone else has the same question. I don't know if there may be a better way to do this, but this is the best I found.

Javascript:

```
var player;
var ytSeconds = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function ()
    {
    player = new YT.Player('yt-embed', {events: {
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
      });
    });

function onPlayerStateChange(e)
{
  if (e.data == 1 && ytSeconds > 0) {
    e.target.seekTo(ytSeconds);
    ytSeconds = 0;
  }
}

function seekTo(seconds)
{
  if (player.getPlayerState() == 1) {
    player.seekTo(seconds);
  }
  else {
    ytSeconds = seconds;
    player.playVideo();
  }
}
```

Then links just look like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="seekTo(120);">02:00</a>
```

Comment: Does this still work? I installed the code into my header but am not having success when I run `seekTo(120)` in the console.

Comment: Same here, this doesn't seems to work now...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the embed code like this. Use  ?start=100&end=250

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/N8VCzpXJZvM?start=100&end=250&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks. But that's not quite what I'm looking for. I want to start at the beginning of the video. But I want to link to specific topics throughout the video, and when the link is clicked, the video jumps to that point.

Answer (score -1):

There are good samples.

https://12starsmedia.com/blog/embed-youtube-video-specific-start-time
http://www.youtubestartend.com/

You can use ?start= to define start points

Comment: Same as above. I want to start at the beginning. But I want to link to specific topics throughout the video, like a table of contents almost. You'll see that in some video descriptions, where they link to the start of each topic, and then it jumps to that time.

Comment: first link is dead